# Why get_post_meta not returning JSON?

Tags: php, wordpress, jsonschema

I am trying to use get_post_meta and a custom field to populate JSON-ld. Note* the information in the JSON is just for testing purposes.

**Custom field name:** schema
**Custom field value:**

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
 "@context": "http://schema.org",
 "@type": "LocalBusiness",
 "address": {
   "@type": "PostalAddress",
   "addressLocality": "Example Town",
   "addressRegion": "Essex",
   "streetAddress": "123 Example Street"
 },
 "description": "A super shop that sells everything at super low prices.",
 "name": "Super Shop",
 "telephone": "01234567890"
}
</script>
```

**the get_post_meta PHP:**

```
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js no-svg">
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
<?php
global $post;
$schema = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'schema', true);
if(!empty($schema)) {
    echo $schema;
}
?>
</head>
```

I insert the PHP in the themes **header.php** file just before the closing `</head>` tag.

Update, clear cache, refresh, nothing happens. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You mean nothing happens as in "I don't _see_ anything on the page" ... as is commonly the case with `script` elements ...?

Comment: Yes, the script is not populated to the page.

Comment: if you `echo get_the_ID();` is it the correct post ID from where you want to fetch the post_meta?

Comment: code seems fine, are you sure the meta is set and you checking the correct page?

Comment: code working without any errors. make sure, that meta_key is right, the post have that meta

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see all of your code I am going to assume that you are not in a WordPress loop and the issue is that get_the_ID() only returns the post ID of the current item in the WordPress loop.  Reference the current page/post by using the following.

```
global $post;
$schema = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'schema', true);
```

Comment: @BrianCampbell post it in the original question.  From what I can see the issue is you need to reference global $post like I have written in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, first time user struggling at formatting comment.

Comment: added to original question

Comment: @BrianCampbell check $post->ID returns a value then check that your post_meta exists in the database by using a tool such as phpmyadmin to browser the post_meta table.